# Parse and print only the stack trace when Regex pattern matches

Tags: java

I want to print just the stack trace starting from and `at cab.ces.upgrade.controller.UpgradeRecommendationController.getPackageOffers(UpgradeRecommendationController.java:1234)`. This is how I get output.
`**** Error Wed Jul 05 23:23:49 GMT 2017    1499297029577   /lll/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-23596/cab/ces/upgrade/manager/business/UpgradeRecommendationsBusinessManager      at cab.ces.upgrade.controller.UpgradeRecommendationController.getPackageOffers(UpgradeRecommendationController.java:1234)`

So I need to remove `**** Error Wed Jul 05 23:23:49 GMT 2017    1499297029577   /lll/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-23596/cab/ces/upgrade/manager/business/UpgradeRecommendationsBusinessManager`

My Code

```
if((strLine.contains("**** Error") )){
                            //|| (strLine.contains("(CreditCheckManager")
                            //String sPattern = "\\tat (.*)\\.(.*)\\(([^:]*):?([\\d]*)\\)";
                        Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);
                        if(m.find()){
                            totCount++;
                            iCount++;

                        if((iCount==1) ){
                            System.out.println("Class name:- " + m.group(3));
                            System.out.println("Line Number:- " + m.group(4));
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("VodafoneSystemException occurence count: " + exCount);
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("VodafoneSystemException stack trace count: " + totCount);

                        }

                        System.out.println(strLine);
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How do I avoid `**** Error ` line so that only the stack trace is printed

Comment: If you are dealing with exception and want to print specific line from stack trace use this `StackTraceElement[] elements = ex.getStackTrace();
Syso(elements[line_number_of stacktrace]);`

Comment: sometimes are situation, when regex technology istn the best. This is such situation

Comment: I understand but we are asked not to use any tool like Elastic Search Kibana which makes my work easy. So  worked on 9 different Exceptions. And I finally used split function to print the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Use `at (.)+` to find all string after at, See [regex](https://regex101.com/r/2XMmDB/5)

Comment: I am using this regex `at (.*)\\.(.*)\\(([^:]*):?([\\d]*)\\)` which matches all the stack trace and prints it. Only thing is how to remove that `**** Error` line.